# Trouble Identifying a "Psi" Function in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In these lecture notes on number theory I am reading I came across the notation $\Psi(e^t;a,q)$ in connection with the Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progression. I was hoping someone could help me identify some candidates for this function so I can make it through this segment of the notes. Thanks!

Comment: Without context, it could mean (almost) anything. It could be the number of primes congruent to $a$ modulo $q$ up to $e^t$, or the sum of the logarithms of those primes, or something else entirely. Is there a URL for these lecture notes?

Comment: Unfortunately not. To provide some additional context the notes set $f(t) = \Psi(e^t;a,q)e^{-t} - 1/\varphi(q)$ and then use an argument similar to Newman's proof of the PNT to deduce the theorem on arithmetic progressions. Hopefully this helps some.

Comment: Well, then I'm guessing it's the sum of $\log p$ as in my comment, or the sum of the von Mangoldt function over those primes. Try that, see if it works. Or compare it with another treatment of the same theorem, such as the one in Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory.